# Cannot run project from SVN repository

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn

I've never worked with SVN-repositories before.
My co-worker gave me access to his repository, I downloaded the SVN plugin for eclipse, established a connection and checked out the java project. It's now locally available, but unfortunately it's not possible to run it.
I have the feeling, that Eclipse doesn't recognize this project. My other Java project are of course executable.

These are the project properties of my random test Java project:
[image]

And these are the project properties of the checked out project. As you can see, some attributes (e.g. Java) are missing:
[image]

Also the project name has a strange additional character:

> "> software"

When I try to add a run configuration, I only can choose my random test project:
[image]

PS: The SVN project works with Maven dependencies. I've installed Apache Maven 3.2.1 and the m2e plugin and linked the directory with Eclipse:
[image]

Could Maven be the problem?
Thank you!

Comment: It's not a java project, notice it's missing the little J.  RClick > Configure > Convert to Java Project and it should be good.

Comment: Honestly, I would get your co-worker to help you.  He obviously has this project working correctly on his own machine; so he should be able to help you to get YOUR machine sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the .project file and the .classpath file...

Those file tells to Eclipse the kind and the structure of the project...

So if they are missing this could cause a lot of problems...

Those file will be also generated if you do something like Configure > Convert to Java (like azurefrog tells in comments)

Answer (score -2):

Right click on your project> team> disconnect. Hope so this will help.